# Can not un-ban a facebook user from my Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to un-ban a user from a Facebook app using the following code. Yet it is not un-ban the user:

```
<?php
$app_id = 'App_id';
$app_secret = 'secret';
$ban_user = 'FB_id';

// Get an App Access Token
$app_token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
. 'client_id=' . $app_id
. '&client_secret=' . $app_secret
. '&grant_type=client_credentials';

echo '<pre>';
echo $app_token_url;
echo '</pre>';

$app_access_token = file_get_contents($app_token_url);

echo '<pre>';
echo $app_access_token;
echo '</pre>';



// Un-ban user
$unban_user_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. $app_id . '/banned/' . $ban_user . "&method=delete?"
. $app_access_token;
$unban_user_result = file_get_contents($unban_user_url);
echo $unban_user_url;
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Unban user result: ' . $unban_user_result;
echo '</pre>';
```

The code is from an example that Facebook supplies and I was able o Ban a user successfully

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2013/08/15/facebook-api-banning-users-from-your-application/) provides an example of how to ban a user using the Graph API and the Facebook PHP SDK.

You code should be calling:

```
$unban_user_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. $app_id . '/banned/' . $ban_user . "&method=delete&access_token="
. $app_access_token;
```

i.e. You're missing `...&access_token="
    . $app_access_token`